# AS3: Set Type and Value simultaneously in Object Hash

Tags: actionscript-3, object, hash

I want to create an object in the form of a hash for coding convenience, but I don't know how to set type and value at the same time.  I'm looking for something like this:

```
var hash:Object = {hp:Number=5};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't will be possible to set the type. I recommend you to create a Hash (or something else) Class, and add your hp propriety.

Something like:

```
public class Hash
{
    private var _hp:Number;

    public function Hash() 
    {
        this.hp = 5;
    }

    public function get hp():Number
    {
        return _hp;
    }

    public function set hp(hp:Number):void
    {
        _hp = hp;
    }
}
```

And be able to use like

```
 var hash:Hash = new Hash();
 trace(hash.hp);//5
```